# How to replace different characters with regex and add conditionals.

Tags: javascript, regex

Example string: `George's - super duper (Computer)`

Wanted new string: `georges-super-duper-computer`

Current regex: `.replace(/\s+|'|()/g, '-')`

It does not work and and when I remove the spaces and there is already a `-` in between I get something like `george's---super`.

Comment: Probably safest to strip invalid characters using regex, split that result on the remaining whitespace using something like input.split(/[ ,.-]+/); and then join the array using something like output=myarray.join("-");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Your regex is malformed. Also you can't conditionally remove `'` and `\s ( )` in a single expression.

---

Your regex is malformed since `(` and `)` have special meanings. They are used to form groups so you have to escape them as `\(` and `\)`. You'll also have to place another pipe `|` in between them, otherwise you're going to match the literal `"()"`, which is not what you want.

The proper expression would look like this: `.replace(/\s+|'|\(|\)/g, '-')`.

However, this is not what you want. Since this would produce `George-s---super-duper--Computer-`. I would recommend that you use [Character Classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which will also make your expression easier to read:

`.replace(/[\s'()-]+/g, '-')`

This matches whitespace, `'`, `(`, `)` and any additional `-` on or more times and replaces them with `-`, yielding `George-s-super-duper-Computer-`.

This is still not quite right, so have this:

```js
var myString = "George's - super duper (Computer)";

var myOtherString = myString
  // Remove non-whitespace, non-alphanumeric characters from the string (note: ^ inverses the character class)
  // also trim any whitespace from the beginning and end of the string (so we don't end up with hyphens at the start and end of the string)
  .replace(/^\s+|[^\s\w]+|\s+$/g, "")

  // Replace the remaining whitespace with hyphens
  .replace(/\s+/g, "-")

  // Finally make all characters lower case
  .toLowerCase();

console.log(myString, '=>', myOtherString);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do `match` instead of `replace` then `join` result on `-`. Then you may need a `replace` to remove single quotes. Regex would be:

```
[a-z]+('[a-z]+)*
```

JS code:

```js
var str = "George's - super duper (Computer)";
console.log(
  str.match(/[a-z]+('[a-z]+)*/gi).join('-').replace("'", "").toLowerCase()
);
```